# Emergency Mode in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, systemd

I recently installed Ubuntu and after completing the installation process everything seemed to work fine. But when I restarted the system it showed:

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view 
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" 
to boot into default mode.
```

I have tried using `systemctl default` and `exit` both but I am not even able to access my system. It keeps on showing the same message. Please help me solve this issue asap.

This is what it keeps on showing:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like something went wrong during the install. Try re-installing it again

Comment: I am not able to get past this screen.

Comment: How do I install it again?

Comment: I assume you installed it via a USB boot device or CD? You would install it the same way. If you have not done it this way, let me know how you did it

Comment: I installed it via usb

Comment: You'd install it the same way you did previously then. Turn off your machine, insert the USB, when the option comes up for boot options: press it, boot from your USB and follow the install instructions from there. If the issue comes up again after you re-install the OS, Might be something wrong with the image you are installing. 

In that case, try installing a different version of Ubuntu/Linux OS

Comment: Thank you it worked. I installed it again using the USB drive and it is working fine now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Also the error shows `nouveau` which means you have Nvidia graphics card. I suggest you install the recommended Nvidia drivers.